# Using a mocked object as a result for a mocked function

Tags: mocking, phpunit

Please consider this function

```
public static function load($ID, $iConnectionType=NULL)
{
    $oStatement = self::getLoadStatement($ID);
    if ($oStatement->rowCount() == 0) {
        throw new \ObjectNotFoundException($ID, 'Unable to load asset');
    }

    $oItem = self::loadFromStatement($oStatement);
    $oItem->setConnectionType($iConnectionType);

    return $oItem;
}
```

Now I would like to test this function.

What I have so far is:

```
public function testLoad()
{
    $oMockedPDOStatement = $this->getMockBuilder('\PDOStatement')
        ->setMethods(array('rowCount'))
        ->getMock();
    $oMockedPDOStatement->expects($this->any())->method('rowCount')->will($this->returnValue(1));

    $mockedObject = $this->getMockBuilder('AssetFactory')
        ->setMethods(array('loadFromStatement', 'getLoadStatement'))
        ->getMock();
    $mockedObject::staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('getLoadStatement')
        ->will($this->returnValue($oMockedPDOStatement));
    $mockedObject::staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('loadFromStatement')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new TestAsset()));

    $this->assertInstanceOf('TestAsset', $mockedObject::load(5));
}
```

The problem is when running this test I get the following failure

1) AssetFactoryTest::testLoad
ObjectNotFoundException: Unable to load asset

What I would think is that the `oMockedPDOStatement` will take care of the `$oStatement->rowCount()` but apparently this is not so. What would be the solution to test this properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with late static binding (or that you are not using it).  In order to test this, your code needs to use `static` instead of `self`.  Your test is calling the actual methods rather than using the mocked methods.

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html

Your function needs to become:

```
public static function load($ID, $iConnectionType=NULL)
{
    $oStatement = static::getLoadStatement($ID);
    if ($oStatement->rowCount() == 0) {
        throw new \ObjectNotFoundException($ID, 'Unable to load asset');
    }

    $oItem = static::loadFromStatement($oStatement);
    $oItem->setConnectionType($iConnectionType);

    return $oItem;
}
```